# qpid proton on_sendable is called just once

Tags: c++, qpid

I am implementing Qpid proton client with C++.

Qpid version is 0.12.2.

I run default container:

```
proton::container(myHandler).run();
```

MyHandler is like this:

```
void MyHandler::on_start(proton::event& e) {
proton::connection conn = e.container().connect(url);
_senderEvent            = conn.open_sender(EVENT_RECEPTION);
}

void MyHandler::on_message(proton::event &e) {
}

void MyHandler::on_link_open(proton::event &e) {
    std::cout << "LINK OPEN " << std::endl;
}

void MyHandler::on_connection_open(proton::event &e) {
}

void MyHandler::on_sendable(proton::event &e) {
    std::cout << "on sendable! " << std::endl;
}
```

Every thing works fine! It connects, create sender, etc.

But, `on_sendable` is called just once! Although I dont close it, it nevers return to call `on_sendable`.

What could be the reason?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have found the answer to this question by yourself but from what I understand on_sendable will be called after you open a sender and then every time after you send a message over proton. If you never send messages then on_sendable will be called just once.